# Why are thumbnails of video files on Android black or green while they are fine on other platforms?

Tags: android, mp4, android-videoview

An Android app generates video files (MP4), so I have full control of the MP4 files. I am trying to figure out why the thumbnails do not work on Android. The MP4 files play flawlessly on Android. When these Android app-generated MP4 files are transferred to a Windows PC, they also play perfectly and the thumbnails are perfect too.

I wonder if anyone with knowledge of how Android generates thumbnails offers a hint on how to remedy this. Here is the structure of the MP4 files:[image]

Here is a [sample file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ORzkmrmunGs_TMPHdB783BFUCOBkmV3n/view?usp=sharing).

**Edit**:

Here is a screenshot showing 4 of those MP4 files with black thumbnails along with an MP4 file generated differently with a correct thumbnail:
[image]

Comment: You should explain what 'thumbnails' are you referring to: your own code (please show), a third-party app, MediaStore, other library?

Comment: Do you mean the code to generate those MP4 files? There are a few thousand linesin about 50 files. MP4 files are generated from raw H.264/H.265 and AAC audio frames.  I am not sure how helpful they would be. I thought the structure of those MP4 files was better in showing how they comply with the ISO Base Media File Format. I will add a screenshot to show the thumbnails.

Comment: No how are you checking thumbnails of your generated MP4 files on Android? What code is generating the thumbnail image (or what apps are you using for test)?

Comment: I check the thumbnails by looking at gallery apps on Android devices (e.g., Google Photos) - a typical way of using media files. I have no idea how video files' thumbnails are generated on Android. That is exactly what I hope some experts can shed some light on.

Comment: @Hong I see from a quick look that your MP4 has I-frames but not any IDR keyframes. An IDR keyframe is a complete image and usually the first frame is type IDR. Maybe the problem is that Android expects frame 1 to be  IDR (if that is lacking then you get black, and getting green would mean a badly decoded keyframe). Microsoft seems to detect lack of IDR and generates a thumbnail from first frame (using its own decoder).

Comment: @VC.One Thank you. I will try to add sync sample table('stss') to the video track to see if it will make any difference.

Comment: @Hong Is it solved now? If not then upload an updated MP4 and I will check what else is missing...

Comment: @VC.One Thanks a lot.  I am yet to add 'stss'. I am traveling now. I will get back to this in 2 weeks.

Comment: @VC.One I have finally figured out. Your original remark is correct - Android requires keyframes (i.e., the 'stss' table) to show thumbnails correctly. If 'stss' table does not exist, the first frame being an IDR will work too. I had errors in the 'stss' that I created yesterday. The thumbnails work fine now after the errors were fixed. Could you turn your comment into an answer for me to accept?